# Debian: What Are Permissions/User Requirement To scp From local server to remote server

Tags: ssh, debian, scp

I have two LANs with routers tunneled to communicate with my Debian servers over the Internet. That works fine. I can SSH with certificates so as not requiring password to connect local server1 user (Tom) to remote server user (Harry). I am confused as to setting the directory permissions, owner and groups on the remote server directories so as to scp files from my local LAN server(s) to the remote server without getting Permission Denied. I could complicate this question further by stating the local LAN has 3 servers and a NAS plus I hope to automate this with Perl and crontab. Though just the basics in helping to clarify this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A file system `Permission denied` error has nothing to do with your
SSH connection.  Only the permissions granted to the userids at each
end matter.  Consider:

```
$ whoami
tom
$ scp foo harry@remote:bar
```

- User `tom` must be able to read pathname `foo`.

  - You can test this without using `scp` -- just try to read the
    file `foo`.
- User `harry` must be able to write pathname `bar` on `remote`.

  - You can test this without using `scp` -- just login to `remote`
    as `harry` and try to write the file `bar` (as `harry`).

If either of the above tests fail, the `scp` will fail.

For example:

```
$ scp /etc/shadow harry@remote:bar
/etc/shadow: Permission denied
```

Local user `tom` cannot read `/etc/shadow`.

```
$ touch foo
$ scp foo harry@remote:/etc/shadow
scp: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
```

Remote user `harry` cannot write to `/etc/shadow`.